# How to open the apple app store internally using a modal segue

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, uistoryboardsegue

I am currently making an app that recommends other apps to download on the apple app store. I assumed that the only way for users to download these linked apps was to call the iTunes URL of the particular app -> the apple app store would then open pushing the original calling app into the background -> then the user would press the download button here as per normal.

Then I was playing with the app "App Hero" and they do something I thought wasn't possible. You can actually download another app to your device without ever leaving the "App Hero" application. I thought this was impossible due to sandboxing. They have a modal segue to what appears to be an embedded app store where you can commence installation of another app. This "embedded" app store doesn't have the usual UITabBar running along the bottom but everything else is basically the same.

Does anyone have any idea how they would have achieved this? It doesn't appear to be a UIWebView, perhaps I am wrong. And is this against any of the apple regulations?

*This is no way an advertisement for "App Hero". I am genuinely impressed/confused how they are able to do this and would love this functionality in my own app if it is allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class you are looking for is called `SKStoreProductViewController`. Docs [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKITunesProductViewController_Ref/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: perfect answer, thanks. Must have been searching the wrong keywords